# How to reference functions and state from inside a fetch request REACT

Tags: javascript, fetch, state

I found the error in my code, I was calling a function outside of my fetch promise which resulted in the app not updating sometimes when updating the user search list. So in the final .then function I am unsure how to reference this.importantfunction(this.importantarguments) as I usually would when theyre outside the fetch request. In this format they result in being undefined.

```
sendfriendrequest = (e, friend) => {
        console.log("You want to be friends with: " + friend);
        let thetitleofsomeonewewanttobecloseto = friend;
        let username = this.state.username;
        fetch(currentrooturl + 'users/requestfriendship', {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                credentials: 'same-origin',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    thetitleofsomeonewewanttobecloseto, username
                })
            })
            .then(function(response) {
                // You parse the data into a useable format using `.json()`
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function(data) {
                // `data` is the parsed version of the JSON returned from the above endpoint.
                // console.log("data: " + data);  // { "userId": 1, "id": 1, "title": "...", "body": "..." }
            console.log(data);
                return data;
            })
            .catch(error => { console.log(error);
            })
            .then(function(data) {
                this.limitedsearch(this.state.username, this.state.searchusers[0].length);
            })


        e.preventDefault(console.log(thetitleofsomeonewewanttobecloseto));
        // research users to update list
        // this.limitedsearch(this.state.username, this.state.searchusers[0].length);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [arrow functions](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/) for the promise handlers to avoid redefining `this`:

```
fetch().then((data) => {
  this.limitedsearch(this.state.username, this.state.searchusers[0].length);
});
```

Notice the `(data) => {}` syntax.

Using arrow functions, `this` will not be redefined. Instead, it will be set to the same value as `this` in the parent context, giving you the functionality you want.

Admittedly, `this` can be a confusing topic. I recommend reading up on the [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword to understand the topic further.

Comment: Thankyou for this, this cleared up my confusion with arrow functions now I much better understand their usage.

Answer (score 0):

Before the fetch function, you can store a reference to `this` and then in the `then()` you can use that reference...

```
sendFriendRequest = (e, friend) => {
    /* some code here */
    let self = this; // Reference to this
    fetch(/* some function arguments here */)
        /* some then()s here */
        .then(function(data) {
            self.limitedsearch(self.state.username, self.state.searchusers[0].length);
            self = null; // Destroy reference to avoid memory leaks
        })

};
```

Comment: Thankyou this was very informative. I could have just used an arrow function but this was an interesting technique to use